# Alphabetical/Numerical order sort - jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, symfony

I have a little autocomplete in my project with jQuery UI plugin fot the autocomplete. But elements I enter in my table, goes out not in order, like this:

[image]

here is the firebug showing the network:

[image]

And here is my autocomplete:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var $search = $( "#city_name" );

        $search.autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax( {
                    url: '{{ (path("app_autocomplete_city")) }}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( data );
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here my controller where I do the JSON response:

```
public function ajaxAutoCompleteCityAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $cities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:City')->getCityAutocomplete($request->query->get('term'));

        $formattedData = array();
        foreach ($cities as $city) {
            $formattedData[] = array(
                'value' => $city['name'],
            );
        }
        return new JsonResponse($formattedData);
    }
```

So I wonder how can I put this in alphabetical/numerical order to be able to have a nice output.

Thank you

Comment: You can use the `sort()` method to order the data. Exactly what the logic would look like depends on what the `data` variable holds. Could you edit your question include a sample of it

Comment: hello @RoryMcCrossan. Yes I was thinking of `sort()` but where should I put it? should I write `success: function( sort( data ) )` ?

Comment: What is this `autocomplete` plugin? `Symfony` is for backend PHP I think, so it has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: You will most likely need to implement the logic to do the sort yourself, it's not quite as simple as calling `sort()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control - this is why I asked for the sample of your data

Comment: Can you post a sample JSON of your response.

Comment: I edited my post and added the code where I actually treat the JSON. I don't know if that is what you wanted? Also the plugin I am using is the jQuery UI plugin

Comment: If you have control of the response, then it would be better to do the sort on the server side instead of JS

Comment: @criss-cross, you can preview the data in Chrome Dev Tools `network` tab: http://commandlinefanatic.com/art034f005.png
We need this data in order to find a way to sort it.

Comment: I guess I didn't thought this was so complicated :/ even in the controller I cannot do it? Anyway thank you for your answers, but I might not very much find how to do it actually

Comment: @Tymek I updated my answer, thanks for the advice I didn't know what it was :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use method [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) & add the city name to the array key & then sort it by key like this in backend

```
$formattedData = array();
foreach ($cities as $key => $city) {
     $formattedData[$city['name']] = array(
       'value' => $city['name'],
     );
}
ksort($formattedData);
return new JsonResponse($formattedData);
```

Comment: hello, what does `valueArr = array();` actually do in the code? Because I don't understand it. Does this will sort in alphabetical order my problem?

Comment: Ohh Sorry . Removed the empty array. used other approach to solve this but this one is easy. I forgot to delete it. Updated the answer

Comment: @crisscross This will output the array in order

Comment: I'm checking, will let you know :)